# Write state space values from MATLAB to the state space block in simulink

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink

How can I write the A, B, C, and D matrices which I've generated in MATLAB to a state-space block in Simulink? I have an `ss` class variable from which I can extract those matrices. Perhaps there is some sort of helper function which takes the `ss` variable and writes the matrices to the block automatically?

The reason I ask is because it can be quite cumbersome writing those matrices manually in the fields if there are a ton of states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Simulink's State-Space Block and your A, B, C, D matrices are variables inside your global workspace, you should be able to just type those into the state space block and have it automatically update when the values of the matrices change.

> ... [U]se your workspace commands to create four matrices A,B,C,D. Then go into your Simulink model, and double-click to open your State-Space block, then under the field of parameter A, just type A again, then under B, type B again, and so on.

[Source](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152993-how-to-import-matrices-from-workspace-to-simulink-block)